# C++ code fails in AWS with error "cannot allocate memory" when using system(command)

Tags: c++, linux, system

I have a C++ code which has been used for many years. Recently I put it in AWS but failed with error. I located the error and found the following code caused the failure.

```
string command = "echo hello";
int ret = std::system(command.c_str());
if (ret != 0)
{
    cout << strerror(errno);        
    return false;
}
```

The error message is `cannot allocate memory`. The `system(command)` is called within my main program which consumes a lot of memory. I have done a lot of searching of `system` and such a failure. Some other people have had the same error. Many suggest using the equivalence of `system` and some say one may develop his own equivalence of `system`. I will appreciate anyone who could provide an equivalence of `system`.

Comment: The equivalent code is `cout << "hello" << endl;` and is indeed less likely to fail due to memory...

Comment: What are your `ulimit(1)`s? Both `fork` and `execve` document `ENOMEM` ...

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful that the memory runs out just exactly when you need some bytes here..
I would assume that the error message is incorrect or at least misleading; my first guess is that you would have an issue to run any `system` calls in any context - maybe authorization, or not supported, or such.

Try to create a simple program with nothing in it, just a system call. If that fails already, you know that the issue is not with your program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I am quite sure that it is caused by memory since the program is runnable with a larger memory node. I am tring trying to create my own `system` function.

Comment: Now that I thought about it, `system` starts a whole shell with environment variables etc, so it _could_ be quite a chunk needed.